# allow just number in a gridviewcell on editing

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a gridview in my C# windows application ... It allowed to be edited and I want a special cell (named "Price") to just allow number on keypress ... I use the code below for texboxes to just allow numbers ... in which event of grid view should I write this code?

```
     private void txtJustNumber_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit((char)(e.KeyChar)) &&
            e.KeyChar != ((char)(Keys.Enter)) &&
            (e.KeyChar != (char)(Keys.Delete) || e.KeyChar == Char.Parse(".")) &&
            e.KeyChar != (char)(Keys.Back))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just check for which cell is being edited on key press and then handle the key press event accordingly?

Comment: @Derek I have some other textboxes on the form ... how can i handle all of them! can u explain more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thx guys ... I used below code and my problem resolved ...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod();
    }

    private void MyDataGridViewInitializationMethod()
    {
        gvFactorItems.EditingControlShowing +=
            new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(gvFactorItems_EditingControlShowing);
    }

    private void gvFactorItems_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress); ;
    }

    private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!char.IsDigit((char)(e.KeyChar)) &&
            e.KeyChar != ((char)(Keys.Enter)) &&
            (e.KeyChar != (char)(Keys.Delete) || e.KeyChar == Char.Parse(".")) &&
            e.KeyChar != (char)(Keys.Back))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use CellValidating event of DataGridView.


private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Validate the Price entry.
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Price")
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: then... how should I validate the pressed key? "e" is not same as the "e" in KeyPress event...

Comment: I told you about event as you asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at this, it will help :-

[DataGridView keydown event not working in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284370/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working-in-c-sharp)