# How to detect Down and Up Arrow Keys While DridGridView is in Edit Mode

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, listbox, doskey

I'm working with a `DataGridView` in `vb.net` which populating a `listbox` while editing. How ever I'm trying to move the **focus** to the listbox by pressing the down arrow key. But the default down arrow key property is not working while the `DataGridView` is in **edit mode**. So is there anyway to override the function of the down arrow key in the DataGridView ?

Comment: use keydown event for datagridview.specify if down key is pressed focus moves to list box.

Comment: Breaking basic navigation in the grid is quite unwise, your user is going to hate you.  Use the Tab key instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code for your reference

```
Private Sub gridview_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles gridview.KeyDown
if e.keycode=keys.Down
list.focus()
end if
end sub
```

This should work.

Comment: pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284370/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: The example works for Ctrl and Alt key but not for UP and DOWN arrow keys.