# Check If User Pressed Enter to leave DataGridViewCell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working in VB.Net programming user functionality into a `DataGridView`.  Currently, I am trying to allow users to update the data that is being shown in the `DataGridView` by editting what is in the Cells.

Right now I have a method to detect when the user begins the edit the cell:

```
Private Sub dataTable_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dataTable.CellBeginEdit
    oldCellVal = dataTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
End Sub
```

The point of the method is to store the old data in the cell in memory so that it can be restored later if the user decides not to edit the cell.

Now I am not sure how to set up the method for when the user completes the edit.  I know there is a `CellEndEdit` event I can make a Handler for, but in that method how would I detect how they left the Cell?

I'd like to set it up so that if my User presses the **Enter** key, only then is their edit submitted.  If they use the Arrow Keys, or the ESC key to exit the Cell, they instead get a "Would you like to stop editting?" prompt.  This makes it sound like I need a keypress event, but if I do that kind of event, how do I properly detect the Cell that was modified?  I need the know the row and column index of the updated Cell in order to properly submit the changes.

So how should I go about doing this?  `KeyPress` or `CellEndEdit`?  Or is there something else I haven't considered?

Comment: Take a look at this question with its two answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941246/how-to-datagridview-cursor-go-to-next-line-when-press-enter/50945383#50945383). Both answers show how to handle and act on key presses. But this answer is in C#. If it looks close to something you need, I can help translate it to VB.net