# Why can't I capture Ctrl-C in my DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

It's been like an hour. I just want to implement Copy & Paste while editing my DataGridView. Maybe I'm asking too much?

This is what I have so far. Initalization:

```
dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView_EditingControlShowing);
```

I guess which calls:

```
    private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyDown += Control_KeyDown;
    }
```

And we have:

```
    private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("control c");
        }
    }
```

I can capture Control. I can capture C. I can't capture Ctrl-C. It's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyDown` event is only triggered when a cell is in edit mode in the `DataGridView`, so the keyboard shortcut event catcher will not work in other cases. You can fix this problem by pointing the `KeyDown` event handler as follows:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
   {
      DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;

      tb.KeyDown -= dataGridView_KeyDown;
      tb.PreviewKeyDown -= Control_KeyDown;

      tb.KeyDown += dataGridView_KeyDown;
      tb.PreviewKeyDown += Control_KeyDown;
   }
}

private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
   { 
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("control c");
   } 
}
```

A similar discussion is available in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284370/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working-in-c-sharp).